# Why is this query based on edge ngram elasticsearch mapping failing to return any results?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Here is the mapping and analyzer settings below.  Let's say I am indexing a "Book" record. Plural fields on a book record (e.g. publishers and tags) are arrays of string (e.g., ["random house", "macmillan"]) and the field "name" takes a singular string such as "Blue".

```
{
   "state": "open",
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "number_of_shards": "5",
         "provided_name": "autocomplete_index",
         "creation_date": "1509080632268",
         "analysis": {
            "filter": {
               "edge_ngram": {
                  "token_chars": [
                     "letter",
                     "digit"
                  ],
                  "min_gram": "1",
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "max_gram": "15"
               },
               "english_stemmer": {
                  "name": "possessive_english",
                  "type": "stemmer"
               }
            },
            "analyzer": {
               "keyword_analyzer": {
                  "filter": [
                     "lowercase",
                     "english_stemmer"
                  ],
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "standard"
               },
               "autocomplete_analyzer": {
                  "filter": [
                     "lowercase",
                     "asciifolding",
                     "english_stemmer",
                     "edge_ngram"
                  ],
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "standard"
               }
            }
         },
         "number_of_replicas": "1",
         "uuid": "SSTzdTNFStaSiIBu-l3q5w",
         "version": {
            "created": "5060299"
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "autocomplete_mapping": {
         "properties": {
            "publishers": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                     "ignore_above": 256,
                     "type": "keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                     "ignore_above": 256,
                     "type": "keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            "tags": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                     "ignore_above": 256,
                     "type": "keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aliases": [],
   "primary_terms": {
      "0": 1,
      "1": 1,
      "2": 1,
      "3": 1,
      "4": 1
   },
   "in_sync_allocations": {
      "0": [
         "GXwYiYuWQ16wgxCrpXShJQ"
      ],
      "1": [
         "Do_49lZ4QmyNEYUK_QJfEQ"
      ],
      "2": [
         "vWZ_PjsLSGSVh130C5EvYQ"
      ],
      "3": [
         "5CLINaFJQbqVcZLVOsSNWQ"
      ],
      "4": [
         "hy3JYfmuR7e8fc-anu-heA"
      ]
   }
}
```

If I do a query such as:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/autocomplete_index/_search?size=5' -d '
{
"query" : {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "b",
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "fields": ["_all"]
    }
  }
}'
```

I get 0 results. I have to put in the full word "blue" in the query field to get a match.

Furthermore, when I do an "_analyze", I get:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/products_autocomplete_dev/_analyze?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
  "field": "name",
  "text": "b"
}
'

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "b",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I would expect to get back tokens such as "b", "bl", "blu", and "blue" at least.

Here is a sample document from the index:

```
{
  "_index" : "autocomplete_index",
  "_type" : "autocomplete_mapping",
  "_id" : "145",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name": "Blue",
    "publishers" : [
      "macmillan",
      "Penguin"
    ],
    "themes" : [
      "Butterflies", "Mammals"
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things with this wrong, that I am suggesting you give a good read of the documentation on analyzers. Hope you don't mind I'm suggesting this.

First of all, if you want to test an analyzer, don't specify the field name as well, only the text and the analyzer itself:

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?pretty
{
  "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
  "text": "blue"
}
```

If you defined a custom analyzer, how should Elasticsearch know that a specific field is using that analyzer? Defining the analyzer is not the same as making a specific field using it. So:

```
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
-->   "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
```

The same goes for the `_all` field: by default, it's using the `standard` analyzer, and it will use the same unless you change it:

```
  "mappings": {
    "autocomplete_mapping": {
      "_all": {
        "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "publishers": {
          "type": "text", 
          "fields": {
.....
```